# script to check if a certain option is checked in bamboo ui

Tags: bamboo

In the bamboo ui,

```
Bamboo plan -> Actions -> configure plan -> Stages & Jobs -> Miscellaneous tab
```

There is an option to check / uncheck

```
 Clean working directory after each build
```

I have a script that will get the url for this edit configuration page and the Miscellaneous tab.

```
Eg:  
http://bamboo.test1.com:8080/build/admin/edit/editMiscellaneous.action?buildKey=ZT-WIN-JOB1
```

Is there a way that I pass this url through a script and find if that option is checked or unchecked? Please let me know.

Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 mydir="/bamboo/artifacts"
 cd "$mydir"

 bambooServer="http://bamboo1.test.com:8080/build/admin/edit/editMiscellaneous.action?buildKey="
 job="-JOB1"
 for dir in */
   do
       bamboourl=`echo "$bambooServer$dir" | sed 's/\/$//g'`$job
       echo  $bamboourl
   done
```

Comment: Could you please show the script you are using to fetch the page? I assume it has to be modified to read the DOM element and output it's value.

Comment: i updated the original post with the script.

Comment: I think using Selenium for getting this value might be a better idea.

Comment: @dhumketu: Thank you! I am actually trying to write a query to get that value from the  database and that seems to be a simpler approach.

Comment: @VRK So you are trying read XML from  BUILD_DEFINITION.XML_DEFINITION_DATA. Be careful, table name and column names keep changing frequently.

Comment: Yes I am conditioning like this
" where bd.XML_DEFINITION_DATA like '%<cleanWorkingDirectory>false</cleanWorkingDirectory>%'  
"